# Use if Interfaces

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface

I have on my C# app 2 class objects:

```
public class Alpha
{
    public string IAmCalledAndy {get;set;}
    public int IAmAnExtraField {get;set;}
}

public class Beta
{
    public string IAmCalledJohn {get;set;}
}
```

I also have 2 methods:

```
public string testMethod1(Alpha myAlphaInstance)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myAlphaInstance));
    return sb.ToString();
}

public string testMethod2(Beta myBetaInstance)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myBetaInstance));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I would like (for the case of tidy up and refactoring to just have 1 method:

```
public string testMethodGEneric(iObjectType myObjectInstance)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myBetaInstance));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

So, I do understand that Alpha and Beta object will need to inherit from an interface called iObjectType but what goes in the iObjectType?

For instance, in reality Class Alpha will contain Customer fields and Class Beta will contain Address fields.

Am I hoping for too much? Can it be done without making it overly complicated that I might as well stick to the original 2 methods?

Comment: It's unclear what you hope to achieve with either the original methods or the combined one. `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` returns a string. So you are creating a string builder, appending a string to it and then extracting that string back out. This simply slows the serializing process. Why can't you just use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` directly?

Comment: @DavidArno Hi, thanks for your comment. I think you need to ignore what the method actual does. I just mocked something up for brevity. I am more concerned whether this architecture/mechanism can be achieved. However, I am leaning towards both class objects exposing another field called 'json' which will return the json string equivalence if that make sense?  It is more of an intellectual question - if I can call it that :)

Comment: Please don't do that. Classes should not mix responsibilities. Having each class provide a json converter for itself would be such a responsibility mix. If you want a single method that does more than your are showing, and that handles both `Alpha` and `Beta`, just have them implement `IObjectType`, which can be an empty interface. However, if you then start having to test whether it's an `Alpha` or `Beta` instance that's being handled in the method, you should keep the two methods separate.

Comment: Please make the code more representative of your problem - `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` has type `object => string` so you don't need separate overloads in the first place. Is the real code calling an overloaded function?

Comment: @DavidArno Hi, sometimes by posing a question it lends itself to an answer straightaway.  I do do unit testing and having it all merged into 1 would have been a disaster for that. I had already came to that conclusion just now and have done as you had recommended.  Now.. do I delete this question becuase it is the wrong thing to achieve or keep it up as a warning to thers? +1 btw

Comment: @lee I understand your point - durhh,  What a dunce I am. I am definitely using the json convertor so you answer below will let me do that.  I am just now embarrassed in posting a really stupid question. Now all the cards are on the table I shall let my peers decided whether this question should be closed. I myself think it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything else, you have your generic function:

```
public string testMethodGEneric(object instance)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

JsonConvert.SerializeObject is already accepting an Object type.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement any number of interfaces, and an interface does not have to contain any methods. The interface without specifying any functionality is called a "Marker Interface"

`IRequiresSessionState` in System.Web is a good example. This interface exposes no methods, but if you implement it with your Http Handler, session state will be available during processing requests in your `ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)` method. Asp.Net will just provide the session state.

Therefore, just have a marker interface, say `IAppEntityBase`, without any methods, and have it in both of your classes.

Comment: Thank you. I know that your problem does not require an interface to be implemented, but what if it had :)

Comment: absolutely, I have bookmarked your answer as something I may need to use in the future..

Comment: :) Thanks. Flattered here.